# Instead of rounding them, PIE disappears with the borders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css3pie, ie7.js

I do not know what might be happening!

I took some pictures to try to help you understand ... follows:

**Internet Explorer 9**
[image: IE9]

**Internet Explorer 8**
[image: IE8]

**Internet Explorer 7**
[image: IE7]

### Code

**Css**

```
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px
behavior: url(/Infra/PIE.htc);
```

**PIE.htc**

PIE.htc is located in the folder:

> /Infra/PIE.htc

Public site: http://bindsolution.com/home/contact

I believe it is some other component that is causing this, but I do not know how to identify it.

I did a test in a separate HTML file (notepad) and everything worked perfectly.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disappearing borders is due to the z-index issue commonly encountered when using PIE -- see the documentation at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index for an explanation and solution.

The broken layout in IE7 appears to be due to errors being thrown from some other JavaScript on your page; it renders correctly at first, then gets messed up after the JS errors. PIE does not appear to be the cause.